# IProgress<T> not firing

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I have the following snipped of code:

```
var progress = new Progress<string>();
var count = 0;
progress.ProgressChanged += (o, transferProgress) => ++count;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ((IProgress<string>)progress).Report(i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

In this case, `count` variable never gets incremented. Why is that?

**UPDATE:**
The events seems to be firing but they are just "late" (as some have pointed below). To give more context, this snippet of code was placed in a Win Forms app in a button click event handler. No matter what I did in the handler (i.e. put a sleep for x seconds), until the button click handler wasn't finished executing the events would not fire. How can I get around this to get "timely" events?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It wouldn't be a problem with the "closure system". Try it: `int i = 0; Action a = () => ++i; a(); Console.WriteLine(i); // --> 1`

Comment: @BradleyDotNET The closure semantics are not relevant at all. What *is* relevant is that callbacks *"are invoked through a SynchronizationContext instance captured when the instance is constructed. If there is no current SynchronizationContext at the time of construction, the callbacks will be invoked on the ThreadPool."* You would have this issue with any callback, closure or not.

Comment: @cdhowie Sounds like a good answer to me :)

Answer (score 4):

From the [`Progress<T>` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Any handler provided to the constructor or event handlers registered with the ProgressChanged event are invoked through a SynchronizationContext instance captured when the instance is constructed. If there is no current SynchronizationContext at the time of construction, the callbacks will be invoked on the ThreadPool.

What is likely happening here is that you do have a synchronization context, and so the callbacks are being delayed until some time later, depending on the behavior of the particular synchronization context that governs the execution of this code.

Note that even if you were not running under a synchronization context, you would not be guaranteed that `count == 10` following the loop body, because the thread pool may not have yet executed all of the callbacks.

Further, since the variable is not declared `volatile` the current thread may not observe changes made by another thread since the runtime/JIT is allowed to cache values that could not possibly change in a single-threaded context. To be safe you would also want to use `Interlocked.Increment(ref count)` inside of the callback in case two callbacks get executed simultaneously, because `++count` is not an atomic operation.  (This is only relevant if the callbacks are getting dispatched via the thread pool.)

tl;dr version is "welcome to concurrency."

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question to confirm you were right. Any ideas how I can get around this "latency?"

Comment: @Mensur Create your own implementation of `IProgress<T>` and use it instead of `Progress<T>`.